# World of All Sentient Races, No Animals

Tags: society, food, agriculture, races, sapience

In a world that has no form of lower life forms, only "sophonts" how would society evolve? I'd say it applys to all animals: land, sea and air. But not plants. Probably. Maybe? Given the idea there are other races, some would probably fare better in some regards. Perhaps a race of horsemen can manage agriculture better than humans since they can plow fields with their stronger bodies, but what else? Lizardmen would probably need meat. There are no "animals" only other sentient races. Most races might work together, I feel like, but there would probably be some races that would be ostracized or attacked for their cannibalism activities following that logic.

Technology I'm even less sure of. No beasts of burden is an interesting question, assuming for example, an all human society, with no such beasts to pull plows, run granary mills, etc. These sort of questions of the relations between races and their societies are what I am trying to get answers for.

Edit: As requested, I'll elaborate on a few details. I didn't do so because I guess I feel awkward gushing about my own story. I will try to amend to make the question more pointed and focused.

In order of corrections as asked below:

In terms of races:

Land races:

- Humans: no real differences from the real world. Notable ethnicity known as "Onatari" are an outcast nation because they eat not only Sophont peoples, but they also specifically go after other humans. Vampire aesthetic.
- Horsemen. Typically more squat than humans, but much, much stronger. Dwarves, when it comes to stature. Herbivores. Typically nomadic.
- Drakes, bipedal turtledragon men. Taller, stronger than humans, strength matched by the Horsemen. Capable of breathing fire, use it to survive in colder climates despite their lizard-like biology. Primarily carnivorous by scorching their meat with their fire, been having a hard time figuring out their place due to this.
- Kobolds, smaller horned lizardman race, akin to a human/halfling relation to drakes. Don't breathe fire, commonly made slaves, especially by Onatari. If there is any race that is targeted for meat harvesting, its them. They're abused.
- Golems, construct race, do not eat organic material. Probable middle-ground source for societies, though they have problems with humanity.
- Catmen: Race of catmen. Mainly including them for a throwaway gag about a male catman getting thrown out of a multiracial brothel for obvious reasons. Obviously quite capable of carnivorous behaviors.
- Birdmen, capable of flight, herbivorous but can also eat meat. Very isolated group, sequestered in mountains and don't interact with other races much because they taste like chicken.
- Arthropods, a caste based race that cover a variety of insects, both flying and non, from ants to bees. Herbivorous, but also capable of eating flesh. Very strong agriculture, likely most alien in mindset of any race.

Sea races:

- Cthulhu-esque squidmen. Chitinous body, appendages like fingers look and probably taste like lobster or crab. Have wings capable of gliding and empowering their swimming. Capable of living on land and sea with little problem. Bit lighter, relatively same height as humans. Capable of carnivorous behavior. Chameleon skin. Eldritch knowledge.
- Seaslugs, large, colorful seaslug beings. Poisonous skin. Most nonhumanoid sophont race. Capable of filterfeeding with microorganisms, but are known as a corrupt race and will eat others for pleasure. Hutt types.
- Sharkmen, another carnivorous race, also a warrior race. Capable of going on land like Squidmen, but require a specially built/enchanted piece of equipment to stay for extended periods.
- Frogmen, herbivorous, semi-aquatic and have absurdly powerful vocal cords and lungs. Simultaneously physically weak and strong in different aspects compared to the baseline. Strong lower body as expected.

What I am really mainly asking about is what would the interaction between races really look like? They are all capable of speech, and learning languages and probably do have common tongues between them. Is it more realistic that things would be in a state of "total war" where its just, kill on sight? Hunt each other constantly? Or would it be, could it be, more civilized? What would that look like? I've imagined the civilizations having systems either that allow for the consumption of meat somewhat, or have illegalized it, treating it much the same as a heinous combination of murder and cannibalism.

Its sort've risen from old books we read. Old disney films, where all the animals have personalities. Lion King paints a really weird picture despite acknowledging the lions eat the other wildlife in the savannah. I have a hard time believing they'd all bow and scrape to the monster who eats their kind. Maybe I'm wrong, though.

Comment: Right. I apologize. I'm working on it at this moment to try and get it more pointed. Its not about evolution, some of that I've already worked out myself, to an extent it works for storytelling. I wasn't sure how much I should stipulate, plus I tend to not like getting super specific on my storywork because I feel like i'm gushing. It'll be updated shortly.

Comment: _What I am really mainly asking about is what would the interaction between races really look like?_ <-- This is a massive topic. You're essentially asking: "Tell me everything about Russian, Chinese, American, French, Egyptian, etc. society and how they interact." This type of question is outside the scope of Stack Exchange's Q&A format (fails the book test: one could write a book(s) on the subject).

Comment: That's a great improvement! But @Frostfyre is correct, you're still asking for too much. The only generalization I could make is that evolving to a point of all-sapient animals means (a) very aggressive and (b) very territorial (yup, they'd fight), but other than that, asking how all those races would interact with each other is too much. Would you be willing to ask about two, and then see if that gives you enough to work out the rest or need to ask another question? If so, that's a vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

i think this depend, but if assuming they are in coexist civilization, i see some of them can live and depend on each other or make some trade exchange, base of my own work which has similar situation.

regarding carnivore food, outside of mushroom provide by arthropod, maybe they can eat unfertilize eggs, some of this intelligent creature clearly the type that breed through egg.

for example the Drake can help in providing heat either for public like chimney or for industrial like forging/smeltering metals, or provide fire for cooking in controlled heat, in exchange for food/money by other intelligent race which i assume the Drake is not fast.

for catmen maybe they are flexible enough to provide exotic dance in brothel, and like cat a good hunter and scout during night, and maybe can work as pest control if you have ratman or mouseman.

regarding horseman i agree they will be good for pulling wagon or plowing the field, which i doubt they can make or design themselves, assuming their body look centaur like rather than bipedal.

regarding lizardman maybe they have ability to walk on wall like gecko outside of good swimmer? if they can, i can see they help in building constructions, or in rescue team job, otherwise they can work in fishing the seaslugmen or chase off the troublesome sharkmen, and provide unfertilize egg.

for chutlhu maybe they can provide squid ink as trade, such ink can be a delicacy or expensive ink for writing and drawing, outside of other sea material like kelp or coral or other expensive stuff only in sea.

sharkmen can help provide guard, at least near water territory against other shark tribe, or make trade like chutlhu by providing sea materials.

frogman can help in singing or bard or in orchestra theater etc anything musical, and provide unfertilize egg.

birdman can provide mail delivery, scouting, or provide air flight to others assuming they manage to lift them and provide unfertilize egg.

arthropods may can help in other labor work, and provide honey or sugar water from their product, or provide mushroom farm which maybe edible for carnivore.

human can create golem which also can work as labor drone or toy but probably lacking compare to the intelligent workforce, or am i mistaken and you mean all this race can make golem?

seaslug and vampire probably get destroy on sight, though vampire may has a solution to coexist like using blood transfusion.